# Storing a value in a nested list with an unknown depth in R

Tags: r, list, nested

I am trying to optimize a code which is very computational-intensive, because it deals with subsets of a 80-elements set.

A crucial step that I want to accelerate is finding if the current subset in my loop has already been treated or not. For the moment, I check if this subset is contained in the already treated subset of the same size k (cardinal). It would be much more faster to store progressively treated subset in a nested list to check if a subset has already been treated or not (O(1) instead of a search in O(80 choose k)).

I had no problem coding a function to check if the current subset is in my nested list of treated subset: `access(treated, subset=c(2,5,3))` returns TRUE iff `treated[[2]][[5]][[3]]==TRUE`

However, I have no idea how to store (inside my loop) my current subset in the list of treated. I would like something like this to be possible: `treated[h] <- TRUE` where h is my current subset (in the above example: `h=c(2,5,3)`)

The main problem that I am facing is that the number of "[[..]]" varies inside my loop. Do I have any other option rather than completing h so that it has a length of 80 and putting a sequence of 80 "[[..]]", like: `treated[[h[1]]][[h[2]]]...[[h[80]]] <- TRUE` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If h is a vector of values then

```
"[["(treated, h)
```

recursively subsets the list items.
For example, I created a (not so highly) nested list:

```
> a
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 1
```

The following command, correctly recursively applies item subsetting to the list:

```
> "[["(a, c(1,2,1))
[1] 3
```

The length of the recursively subsetting vector can vary without fixing the number of [[..]]'s. For example, subsetting two levels of depth with the same syntax:

```
> "[["(a, c(1,2))
[[1]]
[1] 3
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know this command. Is it part of a more general syntax that applies to other things?

Comment: Btw, your solution works in my case (solely) because I never enter an element (i,j,k) in the treated nested list without having first entered element (i,j).

Comment: LISP is one of the languages that influenced the structure of R (in fact I am not a LISPER). In LISP all operators are in fact functions. That's also the case in R: Every operator is a function call.

Comment: So you can even use artihmetic operators as function calls by quoting them and providing operands as arguments (like "+"(3, 5))

Comment: This way, operators can be used inside *ply type functions (including subset operators like "[" and "[[")